# Tomcat Webapp on port 80

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6

I have a webapp on my tomcat server like this:

`mydomain.com:8080/mywebapp`

Then I connect to my webapp, and it is working correctly, but what I want is to see my webapp like this:

`mydomain.com`

So I don't want only tomcat on port 80, I don't want to access my webapp through its name, I want to connect directly using my domain URI.

How can I do this? I want this to work with Linux (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and Windows servers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, but the most common way to solve it is to run Apache as a reverse proxy in front of it. You can find some details [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/proxy-howto.html). This will work on both Linux and Windows. For Linux, you can also use `authbind` to allow Tomcat to bind to port 80.
Just changing the port to `80` in your `server.xml` will not work in Linux, since it would require you to start Tomcat as `root`, which is not a very good idea.

Also, to have your webapp at `/`, you can deploy your war file as `ROOT.war`.

Comment: Great, I think I'll use authbind, using these steps: http://java.dzone.com/articles/running-tomcat-port-80-user

Answer (score 7):

Running any application on a privileged port (those below 1024) requires special privileges. If you do this, you should ensure your instance is [properly hardened](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/security-howto.html).

To configure the port tomcat listens on you have to modify the HTTP connector in conf/server.xml ([server reference documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/http.html#Common_Attributes)):

```
<Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="8443" />
```

To change the context path of an app, you can rename the war file. To deploy it at the root, rename your war file to ROOT.war. Or you can add a META-INF/context.xml in which you can specify the desired context path ([context reference docs](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html#Common_Attributes)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/" />
```

Comment: I already tried the change port to 80 thing, but it doesn't work on linux, maybe it needs some additional steps, but I don't want security risks.

Comment: That's probably because tomcat is not running as root; non-root processes are not allowed to bind to privileged ports. Another great way to deal with this is to implement either mod_jk or setup a reverse proxy using apache.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set apache webserver and configure it to use tomcat.

You need to use `mod_jk` in order to configure apache webserver to communicate with tomcat.

Use this [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html) to set up the `mod_jk`.