# AWS EC2: Unable to switch Tomcat 9 to listen port 80

Tags: tomcat, amazon-ec2

I am running EC2 instance with amazon Linux. I have installed Tomcat 9 and, by default, I am able to access the my application running on Tomcat via port 8080 and 8443.

I just wanted to switch to 80 so that I updated server.xml in the conf folder

```
 <Connector port="80" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           redirectPort="443" />
```

and confirmed no other services running on port 80. Also,confirmed that I have enough inbound rules in the security group to listen port 80

[image]

Unfortunately, still not able to access via port 80.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat Webapp on port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326707/tomcat-webapp-on-port-80) (otherwise search for "tomcat port 80" - there are numerous questions with existing different answers here. On top, it's a configuration question, thus off topic on stackoverflow - see [help/on-topic])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found at least a workaround. I used iptables to redirect in the following way.

```
 sudo /sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8080

sudo /sbin/iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8443

sudo /sbin/service iptables save
sudo /etc/init.d/iptables restart
```

However, still not sure why do we have to do all these?

Answer (score 0):

If you start tomcat using bin/startup.sh by root, it should work. There is a restriction for ports under 1000, which require process owner should be root.

If you start tomcat with `sudo service tomcat start` or `sudo systemctl tomcat start`, the owner of the process is tomcat, not root.

BYW The first process of HTTPD is root. So httpd services work.

You can find owners of processes with `sudo ps -aAl`.